# Haskell : Minimum position

Tags: haskell

I'm beginner in Haskell terms. I have to do an exercise that shows all minimum positions.
 For example: [1,2,3,1,1] => 0,3,4 these are minimum positions.
 I tried to do this in 2 ways, but these doesn't work.
 Please can someone help me with a recursive version?

First:

```
findPos :: [Int]->Int->[Int]
findPos list minimum (list) = [index | (index, e) <- zip [0..] list, e == minimum (list)]
```

Second:

```
findPos :: [Int]->Int->[Int]
findPos list (minim el) = [index | (index, e) <- zip [0..] list, e == (minim el)]


minim :: [Int] -> Int
minim x = if (tail(x)==[]) then head(x)
      else n 
      where n = minim (tail(x))
            n = if n < head(x) then n
            else head(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Problem with your code

```
findPos :: [Int] -> Int-> [Int]
findPos list minimum (list) = ...
```

That's just plain wrong. You're finding the minimum later (with `minimum list`); don't need to pass it:

```
findPos :: [Int] -> [Int]
findPos list = ...
```

### My Solution

Not recursive, but it's how I would personally do it.

I like the zipping solutions a lot, and I am not sure why you opted for the comprehension.

1. Find the smallest element.
2. Zip your data with `[0..]`.
3. Filter out data basing on `snd` being equal to the smallest element.
4. Take out the `fst` of resulting tuples.

<kbd>[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56af6ace5f919378)</kbd>

---

#### Spoiler alert

```
xs = [1,2,3,1,1]

findPos = map fst . filter (\e -> snd e == x) . zip [0..]
    where
        x = minimum xs

main = print $ findPos xs
```

Comment: Only one small detail: In OP the index begins at `0` so the infinite index list must be `[0..]`.

Answer (score 2):

The serious problem with your code is that you have something strange on the left of the function definitions.

In the first case you have:

```
findPos :: [Int] -> Int-> [Int]
findPos list minimum (list) = …
```

What does this mean? Judging by the signature you gave to `findPos`, it takes a list and the element that we are looking for. So the the definition has to be:

```
findPos list m = [index | (index, e) <- zip [0..] list, e == m]
```

and in this case there is no need to call the `minim` function on the right hand side, but instead you’ll have to call `minim` before calling `findPos` to pass it the minimal element like this:

```
findPos' :: [Int] -> [Int]
findPos' list = findPos list (minim list)
```

**Or** you can change your definition to:

```
findPos :: [Int] -> [Int]
findPos list = [index | (index, e) <- zip [0..] list, e == minim list]
```

and in this case you do call `minim` on the right hand side, but the signature of `findPos` becomes different.

---

Now to the recursive minimum function. You should really use pattern matching as much as possible:

```
minim :: [Int] -> Int
minim (x : []) = x
minim (x : xs) = if x < m then x else m
  where
    m = minim xs
```

Otherwise your `minim` is almost correct except for the fact that you define `n` twice.

Answer (score 1):

As a variation on the earlier answers, let's consider a solution where we visit each element of the input list exactly once.  Like earlier answers, this is not an *explicitly* recursive solution, but it uses the recursive function `foldr`.

```
-- | Accumulate function
--
acc :: Ord a => (t, a) -> ([t], a) -> ([t], a)
acc (i, x) z@(is, y) = case compare x y of
  LT -> ([i], x)   -- a new minimum! reinit the list of mins
  EQ -> (i:is, y)  -- equal minimum; add to the list of mins
  _  -> z          -- larger than min; accumulator unchanged

findPos = (Bounded a, Ord a) => [a] -> [Int]
findPos = fst . foldr acc ([], maxBound) . zip [(0 :: Int)..]
```

So we `zip` the indicies (counting from zero) with our list of numbers, apply the fold with the accumulator initialised to `([], maxBound)` (the initial minimum is the largest possible value), then extract the list of indices of the minimum value in the input.

To eliminate the `Bounded` type class constraint (so `findPos` could work with `Integer` or other unbounded ordered types) one could apply the `Maybe` type constructor, which I leave as an exercise.

Tracking the "minimum seen value" as well as the indices where that value was seen makes it possible to build a stream processing machine of which you could ask at any time, "what were the indices of the minimum value in the (*possibly infinite*) input stream *so far*."